# How do I forbid (403) an entire directory with WordPress .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

Someone seems to have misspelled a domain name in an image reference at another website. This is causing my website to be slammed with requests for an image that does not exist. My server is not equipped to handle this. It is constantly sending out 404 (not found) responses, maxing my resource usage and making my hosting provider rather upset.

The other website's administrator is unresponsive.

I think I need to send 403 (forbidden) rather than 404 (not found) responses.

The requests my server is receiving look like this:

```
GET http://www.mywebsite.com/theirdirectoryname/their-file-name.jpg HTTP/1.1
```

Accordingly I tried to add the following to my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .*(theirdirectoryname).* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

This did not work. My server is still responding 404 instead of 403.

Can anyone see what I did wrong?

My server is running WordPress. So there is a WordPress section in my htaccess, as well as a W3TC Browser Cache section, if this makes any difference.

Comment: Have you thought about adding an image as that file name, and then maybe changing the chmod to 440?

Comment: I'm a little worried my server won't be able to handle that either. I'm often getting several requests in one second. My understanding is the 403 response takes the least resources?

Comment: Are you trying to ban access to that entire directory (from browsers and bots)? If so, you could create a .htaccess file in that directory with "Deny from all" in it.

Comment: Have done that now. My server is still returning 404s instead of 403s.

Comment: Where have you put this directive? This directive will need to go at the very top of your .htaccess file. But is should simply be: `RewriteRule ^theirdirectoryname - [F]` (not that that would actually make a difference). It's probably because WordPress is processing this request that your resources are being maxed. A 404 itself should not be a problem.

Comment: I confirm the directive is at the top of .htaccess, in public_html. I tried it with your RewriteRule. I still have 404 responses. Could it have something to do with WordPress?

Comment: Well, if this at the top of your .htaccess file (ie. above the WordPress directives) then WordPress shouldn't be doing anything with the request. Is the 404 response you are seeing generated by WordPress? Or some other custom 404? Or a default server response? It's possible that the server itself is configured to return 404s instead of 403s. If this 404 is not generated by WordPress then serving a 403 instead is unlikely to make a difference in terms of the resource usage on your server (there is no difference between a 404 and a 403 in this respect).

Comment: You could just try adding `anything` (literally) at the top your .htaccess file. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

you will prob need your server admin to place the rules for you, most shared accounts ignore .htaccess rules you have.

But there are a couple of different options here,

1. block the users ip with htaccess (you will find the 1st line already there, place the 2nd line under it)

   ```
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from 777.8.3.2
   ```
2. prevent any leeching of images altogether with apaches httpd.conf file

   ```
   SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://www\.yoururl\.com/" banimages=1
   SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^http://yoururl\.com/" banimages=1
   SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^$" banimages=1
     <FilesMatch "\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$">
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from env=banimages
     </FilesMatch>
   ```

I would probably recommend the 2nd, you dont want to be become a content delivery service for the images you have online.

Comment: "most shared accounts ignore .htaccess rules you have" - although the OP is already using WordPress with mod_rewrite directives in .htaccess that appear to be working OK. (?) `Allow from env` simply checks for the _existence_ of an environment variable, you can't check its value. `Allow from env=banimages=1` would always fail. It should simply be `Allow from env=banimages` (but wouldn't `allowimages` be a more appropriate variable name in this context?).

Comment: @w3d yes most shared hosting do set rules in apache which take precedence over the .htaccess rules. You can generally make some mods that have not yet been defined, or its already set up for wordpress hosting. You may see the .htaccess file there, but it may be completely ignored altogether. The same goes for php.ini, etc.

Comment: @w3d  reference for code above: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DisableImageHotLinking

Comment: Well, if the host is blocking .htaccess and handling the WordPress stuff at a higher level that would be a stinker! :) The referenced document also omits `=1` from the `Allow from env` directive.